# updating adapter within anonymous inner class android

Tags: java, android, parsing, listview, anonymous-types

I'm new to Android. I'm trying to get data from Parse and update the adapter.
I'm extending my adapter from Array Adapter.
In my adapter, I have an image and an text field.

Issues I have: I'm seeing only the last element in the array in my array adapter.

This is my basic set up:

My parse method contains an inner anonymous class findCallBackMethod. 
In the done method of the parse, 
I'm getting the data from Parse and creating a new object to add it to my array list.
This array list is shown in my adapter.
I'm able to see my entire array result list within my done method.

I searched onto stack overflow and followed some suggestions on creating and setting the adapter within this done method.

Tried so far:

- Making the adapter within the for loop. This for loop gets the data from Parse.
- Tried creating a global instance for ArrayList so the arrayList is visible.
  (Didn't help at all)
- I cannot make my array list final as I'll creating this array list within this for loop.
- Question: How do I make my adapter update the list from within this anonymous inner class?

what am i missing here?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Below is my sample of my code:

```
public void searchPlayer(String playerFirstName)
{

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query_players = ParseQuery.getQuery("myDataFile");

    try {
        query_players.whereMatches("FirstName","Patrick");
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); // change this to meaningful message

    }


    query_players.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>()
    {
        public String shortName;
        public int playerID;

        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> playerList, com.parse.ParseException e) {

            if (e == null)
            {
                d("TAG", "Retrieved: size =  " + playerList.size());

                for(int i=0;i<playerList.size();i++)
                {
                    newPlayer = MySingleton.getInstance().newPlayer;
                    arrayOfPlayers = MySingleton.getInstance().arrayOfPlayers;

                    // short name is abbreviated name; got it from Parse
                    // create a single player

                    String shortName = playerList.get(i).getString("ShortName");
                    String firstName = playerList.get(i).getString("FirstName");
                    String lastName = playerList.get(i).getString("LastName");
                    playerID = playerList.get(i).getInt("PlayerID");

                    Log.d("Player", "short name: " + shortName);
                    //newPlayer = new Player();
                    // if (newPlayer != null) {
                    newPlayer.setPlayerShortName(shortName);
                    newPlayer.setPlayerFirstName(firstName);
                    newPlayer.setPlayerLastName(lastName);
                    newPlayer.setPlayerID(playerID);
                    newPlayer.setPhotoUrl(playerList.get(i).getString("PhotoUrl"));

                    Log.d("Player", "the photo url = : " + newPlayer.getPhotoUrl());

                    //adding the new player to the array
                    if (newPlayer != null) {
                        d("Player", "adding the new player to array list ");
                        arrayOfPlayers.add(newPlayer);

                       Log.d("Player", "the new player's last name  in the arrayList " +    arrayOfPlayers.get(i).getPlayerLastName());
                       Log.d("Player", "the new player's photo url  in the arrayList " + arrayOfPlayers.get(i).getPhotoUrl());

                    }


                    //printing the playerlist:
                    for(Player x:arrayOfPlayers) {
                        Log.d(TAG,"printing the list of player's last name within the for: " + x.getPlayerLastName());
                    }


                    lvPlayerList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvPlayerList);
                    aPlayerListAdapter= new PlayerSearchListArrayAdapter(getActivity(),arrayOfPlayers);
                    lvPlayerList.setAdapter(aPlayerListAdapter);
                    aPlayerListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }// end of for

                /* THIS WORKS WITHIN THE INNER CLASS --- TESTED)
                Log.d("Player", "the array size " + arrayOfPlayers.size());
                Log.d("Player", "the player id from the arrayList " + arrayOfPlayers.get(8).getPlayerID());
                Log.d("Player"," the activity in the player fragment: " + getActivity());

                */



            } //end of (e==null)


            else
            {
                d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                //playerArrayList = null;

            }
        }// end of done

    }); // end of inner class
```

My Adapter class:

```
// Adapter for the list: inflates player_list_item
public class PlayerSearchListArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Player>{

    public static final String TAG = "PLAYER_SEARCH_LIST_ADAPTER";
    private ImageView imvPlayer;
    private TextView tvPlayerFullName;


    List<Player> playerList;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;

     public PlayerSearchListArrayAdapter(Context context,List<Player> playerList) {
         //super(context, 0 , playerList);
         super(context,0,playerList);
         mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
         this.playerList = playerList;
     }


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        Log.d(TAG,"inside adapter");
        Log.d(TAG,"activity = " + getContext());


        // get the data item for position
        Player player = getItem(position);
        Log.d(TAG,"player list size from within the adapter: = " + playerList.size());
        Log.d(TAG,"player's last name = " + player.getPlayerLastName());

        // find if the view exists. what that means if we reached the max limit
        // of items to view on the screen, then Android starts to recycle the
        // previous viewable list items.
        // If the view does not exist, we have to create one through the inflater

        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
           // v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.player_list_item,parent,false);
           // check if to attach to root
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.player_list_item,parent,false);

        }


        // find the ids in the tweet_item.xml
        ImageView imvPlayer = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imvPlayer);
        TextView tvPlayerFullName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvPlayerFullName);



        // populate the items
        // ImageUri is the url of the image
        String imageUri = player.getPhotoUrl();
        Picasso.with(getContext()).load(imageUri).into(imvPlayer);
        tvPlayerFullName.setText(player.getPlayerShortName());
        return v;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

My usage of singleton in this case is not correct.
Fixed the issue. I was creating the adapter and the array every single time the loop iterates.
Changing that solved the issue.